# error when running apt-get update on ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am running ubuntu 14 on one of my servers.

When I run sudo apt-get update, I get the error below.

```
W: GPG error: http://cran.rstudio.com trusty/ Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1445181253 KEYEXPIRED 1445181253 KEYEXPIRED 1445181253
```

Should I modify my ppa repository list or take some other action to fix this issue.

**Update:**
I tried removing R from the server using

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove r-base
sudo apt-get --purge remove r-base-core
sudo apt-get --purge remove r-base-recommended
```

However, I am still seeing the same issue with apt-get update.

Comment: fixed after removing reference from /etc/apt/sources.list file

Comment: I would recommend removing the paragraph about java, since the main issue is how to fix the broken key from RStudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed after removing reference from /etc/apt/sources.list file

Answer (score 29):

Look at the "Secure APT" part of https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html:

Adding the key with key ID E084DAB9 fixed the problem for me.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
```

Comment: Part of the issue is the previous Key expired and had to be renewed. If you installed before mid October you might hit this issue. https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2015-October/002458.html

Comment: I think this should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu's  "Software & Updates" GUI tool (or whatever it's called in other distros), check the "Authentication" tab, which lists all keys known to dpkg/apt.  This `E084DAB9` key belongs to "Michael Rutter, marutterATgmail.com". It is the correct GPG key. Do not search for a CRAN substring in the list.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need R you can just remove the cran line from /etc/apt/sources.list and you should be good to go.

sudo apt-key del 1445181253 will remove the offending key.

Comment: solved by removing reference from /etc/apt/source.list file - thanks

Comment: my java installation is still messed up - will look into it next

Comment: Might take a look at this:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get

Comment: Not sure which one you were using but you can install either Oracle or OpenJdk (whichever one you did not have before) and use update-alternatives like it describes at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the abrupt questions but what has java to do with the 3rd party repository that you have set in your repository?

Also I see you are capable to change your repository but not able to read the output of an error.

You can add the missing key for the 3rd party repo:

```
  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2202787
```

Answer (score 1):

In case your firewall blocks port 11371, a more general solution is to force using port 80 when retrieving the new key:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E084DAB9
gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
```